# JPA2 Complex query resultList

Tags: java, rest, jpa, entity

Creating RESTful webservices for a non-relational, baddly designed DB. Problem is: One of the queries needed uses 2 tables that do not contain primary keys and so I cannot create the corresponding entity classes using netbeans wizard. 
Do I have to create them by hand or can I just create an entity class for the query results? (said query uses a lot of joins and nested selects from 7 differente tables).

I'm really stumbed and don't like the idea of creating an entity class by hand.

And no, I can't, for the life of me, redesign the DB...

Comment: If you don't like the idea of creating entities, you shouldn't use JPA, IMHO. Entities are the core, heart and soul of the app. You should create them by hand and know how to do it. Note that if there is no immutable set of fields identifying a row, you won't be able to map the table as an entity anyway.

Comment: That is not hte problem, as I won't be updating anything, just plain old (massive) GET. Do I really need an entity class for a NativeQuery(String); ? And how does it work with the entity manager?